# multiple colors on output of bash spinner

Tags: bash

I have this Bash spinner code:

```
#!/bin/bash
spinner(){
SP_STRING=${2:-"'|/=\'"}
while [ -d /proc/$1 ]
do
    printf "$SP_COLOUR\e7  %${SP_WIDTH}s  \e8\e[0m" "$SP_STRING"
    sleep ${SP_DELAY:-.2}
    SP_STRING=${SP_STRING#"${SP_STRING%?}"}${SP_STRING%?}
done
}

## Adjust to taste (or leave empty)
SP_COLOUR="\e[1;31m"
SP_WIDTH=1.1  ## Try: SP_WIDTH=5.5
SP_DELAY=.3

sleep 7 &
spinner "$!" '/-\|'
```

Is there a way to make it output the spinner in multiple colors? so like every spin it changes colors.

Also, when the spinner runs, the typing line shows up before the spinner and stays there until the spinner is done. What can I edit in the code to make the typing line go under or after the spinner?

Comment: Unless `SP_COLOUR`, `SP_WIDTH` and `SP_DELAY` are used elsewhere, better to make them `local` to `spinner`.

Answer (score 2):

To change the color in every spin, you could define an array of colors:

```
SP_COLORS=("\e[1;31m" "\e[1;32m")
```

And then before the spinner loop, initialize an index into this array:

```
local sp_color_index=0
```

And then inside the spinner loop, increment this index and rotate it appropriately:

```
((sp_color_index = (sp_color_index + 1) % ${#SP_COLORS[@]}))
```

And then use the index to get the next color from the array:

```
SP_COLOR=${SP_COLORS[sp_color_index]}
```

> Also, when the spinner runs, the typing line shows up before the spinner and stays there until the spinner is done. What can I edit in the code to make the typing line go under or after the spinner?

By "typing line", I guess you're referring to the *cursor*.
Instead of moving the cursor under or after the spinner,
it's probably better to hide it before the spinner loop,
and restore it after. You can hide with `tput civis` and make visible again with `tput cnorm`.

Comment: @Darby_Crash With an array, you have simple control over the colors that will show up in predictable order. I don't see what is not simple about this, and I don't think your solution is simpler.

Comment: @Darby_Crash due to your use of `shuf`, an external process, my solution with only native Bash code is most probably faster ;-)

Comment: I was just about to add a comment on the `tput civis` and `tput cnorm` under the questions when I saw the bottom of your answer. Good job.

Comment: @Darby_Crash That's much better. But I don't see why it would be faster than mine. If one of these approaches is faster than the other, I don't think it's significant. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

**Multicolor Spinner**

```
#!/bin/bash
spinner () {
    local SP_WIDTH="$3"
    local SP_DELAY="$4"
    local SP_STRING=${2:-'/-\|'}
    local SP_COLOR=0
    tput civis
    while [ -d /proc/$1 ]; do
        ((RANDOM%2 == 0)) && SP_COLOR=3$((RANDOM%8)) || SP_COLOR=9$((RANDOM%8))
        printf "\e[1;${SP_COLOR}m\e7  %${SP_WIDTH}s  \e8\e[0m" "$SP_STRING"
        sleep ${SP_DELAY:-.2}
        SP_STRING=${SP_STRING#"${SP_STRING%?}"}${SP_STRING%?}
    done
    tput cnorm
}

sleep 7 &
spinner "$!" '' '1.1' '.3'
```

**I have added a construct that grab a random number from colors table everytime that you show SP_STRING.**

**I have also added width and delay like arguments of the function and set all variables to local**

**If you want a random single color, move construct under tput civis line.**

**NOTE**

**You can also choose a color and pass it to the function like argument like in this example**

```
#!/bin/bash
spinner () {
    local SP_WIDTH="$3"
    local SP_DELAY="$4"
    local SP_STRING=${2:-'/-\|'}
    local SP_COLOR="$5"
    tput civis
    while [ -d /proc/$1 ]; do
        printf "\e[1;${SP_COLOR}m\e7  %${SP_WIDTH}s  \e8\e[0m" "$SP_STRING"
        sleep ${SP_DELAY:-.2}
        SP_STRING=${SP_STRING#"${SP_STRING%?}"}${SP_STRING%?}
    done
    tput cnorm
}

sleep 7 &
spinner "$!" '' '1.1' '.3' '35'
```

**The limit is the fantasy...**

**EDIT**

**256 colors version**

```
#!/bin/bash

spinner () {
    local SP_WIDTH="${3:-1.1}"
    local SP_DELAY="${4:-.2}"
    local SP_STRING=${2:-'/-\|'}
    local SP_COLOR=0
    tput civis
    while [ -d /proc/$1 ]; do
        printf "\e[38;5;$((RANDOM%257))m %${SP_WIDTH}s\r\e[0m" "$SP_STRING"
        sleep $SP_DELAY
        SP_STRING=${SP_STRING#"${SP_STRING%?}"}${SP_STRING%?}
    done
    tput cnorm
}

sleep 7 &
spinner "$!"
```

**If you don't pass it arguments i have set a default value for it**