# How to display a loading status in command prompt while our code is executing in bash?

Tags: bash

i am trying to run a code in Linux which might take around 5 minutes, while the code is executing i need to display a loading status in command window. help me in writing this.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: There's lots of threads on this topic already, just google "bash spinning prompt"

Comment: Like [Spinner Animation and echo command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47234947/spinner-animation-and-echo-command/47235185?r=SearchResults&s=1|32.8605#47235185) ? Adjust the text output as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you should add some sort of loading animation which makes it more clear 'stuff' is happening, or at least should be. There are ofcourse many ways to do this, but this is most aesthetically pleasing while being simple at the same time to me.

```
printf "Loading, please wait a moment.\n\n" 

states="/-\|"

while [ -z ${VARIABLENAME+x} ] do
  for (( i=0; i<${#states}; i++ )); do
    sleep 0.75
    echo -en "${states:$i:1}" "\r"
  done
done
```

You should run that, and set a `VARIABLENAME` to stop the loop and use `clear` to remove the last loop that executed and the `printf`.